# CDK Table DynamoDB, Stream configuration Python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

In terraform, it works passing the attributes directly in CDK does not work. Does anyone know how to activate the stream in the DynamoDB table?

```
stream_enabled   = true
stream_view_type = "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are asking how to do so in CDK, with Terraform as your background:

```
from aws_cdk import aws_dynamodb as dynamodb

...

my_dynamo_table = dynamodb.Table(
    self, "LogicalIDForThisTable",
    ...
    stream=dynamodb.StreamViewType.NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES
)
```

In order to use said stream, you need to create an DynamoEventSource object to pass to whatever resource will be consuming the stream:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda_event_sources/DynamoEventSource.html

ie:

```
from aws_cdk import aws_lambda_event_sources as event_source

...

my_dynamo_event_stream = event_source.DynamoEventSource(
    my_dynamo_table,
    starting_position=aws_lambda.StartingPosition.TRIM_HORIZON,
    batch_size=25,
    retry_attempts=10
)

my_lambda.add_event_source(my_dynamo_event_stream)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from aws_cdk import aws_dynamodb as dynamodb
```

...

my_dynamo_table = dynamodb.Table(
self, "LogicalIDForThisTable",
...
stream=dynamodb.StreamViewType.NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES
)

My problen is :

stream_enabled   = true

how to ?
Tanks.

Comment: I assume you meant this to be a comment to the answer (that you've now accepted) - there is no need to do stream_enabled=True - by doing a stream with that the StreamViewType enum it automatically is registered as enabled by CDK.